# Clock/voltage glitching

Tags: voltage, glitch

Is it possible that clock/voltage glitching can happen over remote distances? (Having the necessary equipment.)

Comment: Absolutely! - not really long enough for an answer, or worth an answer with that level of detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: (It's not a problem, but a question) What I'm trying to ask is that if remote clock/voltage glitching like from a distance is possible, let's say from a device on Texas, and the tester is on New York

Comment: I know it isn't, I used a standard comment. Anyway, I don't understand the question at all, can you elaborate, by adding context?

Comment: You know voltage/clock Glitching right? Where you cause a spike or a dip of voltage/clock, what I'm saying, is that can the same thing be done remotely?

Comment: Yes it can. Detonate a nuclear device nearby will be sure to glitch most things. The devil is in the details - what you want to glitch and from how far away. Didn’t they do something similar in Breaking Bad with an EMP generator? Reality was stretched somewhat, but the concept was valid.

Answer (score 0):

For such long range (Texas - NY) there is no technology to influence a common logic circuits.
One way should be invoke the lightning on target place with a rocket fired from a base place.

High frequency transmitters does not work well for long ranges.
On other hand long waves needs a long antena (meters) so logic circuits with very short wiring catch the waves very poorly.

Possible is to make a high power high frequency transmitter with directional antena, however with current technologies the range would be about few kilometers maybe.